# Ask for quick response in job interview due to current job commitments

Tags: interviewing, job-change, united-kingdom, expenses

I have been offered an interview in 2 weeks time for a role in a different city. It is essentially the same as my current job except with a higher salary and is in a better field (for me). The decision on who gets the role will be made within 2 weeks of then.

I think I have a good chance of getting this job as I have a good range of applicable work experience and qualifications.

My current role is with a charity and they are sending quite a few of us abroad as part of a regular trip away (that I have not been on before). The flights and accommodation for this are quite expensive and are getting more pricey by the day.

My worry is that I will end up costing the charity money by allowing them to buy me flights and accommodation only for me to not use them or by delaying until the flights double in price.

Is it a good idea to ask in the job interview to reject my application sooner rather than later if they know they will eventually? How would this make me look to them? Loyal? An idiot? Prudent? I don't want to affect my chances of getting the role however.

Comment: How soon is this trip from happening? Do you have a specific time when giving your notice period?

Comment: What chances are there that they can re-book the travel in the name of your replacement?

Comment: I doubt I would be replaced. They would likely use more consultants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it a good idea to ask in the job interview to reject my application sooner rather than later if they know they will eventually?

I would not recommend telling them to *"reject your application sooner"*, as it has a negative connotation.

If you need to know an *estimate on the time* they will take to make a choice, I suggest you **ask them for such estimate during or when concluding the interview.** Chances are they will also say something like *"we will get to you in X week(s)"*, moment in which you will have an estimate to decide what to do.

After getting the estimate, you should then carefully manage this with your current Notice Period and the time of this possibly upcoming trip.

Do have in mind that *it's not definite that you will be going to that trip*, so don't let go of a better job opportunity just for the possibility of going on a trip on your current gig.

Comment: To be fair, it is definite that I would be going on that trip.

Answer (score 10):

If you feel that bad, you can reimburse the charity of the funds they lay out.

If you ask the potential new employer to reject your application sooner, rather than later, you can pretty much be assured that they will indeed reject you.

It's unfortunate, but you don't want to flag your current employer by refusing an assignment, and you don't know for certain that you will be getting this job or not.

Your current employer may end up being a victim of bad timing, but that is their misfortune, not yours.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a good idea to ask in the job interview to reject my application sooner rather than later if they know they will eventually?

No. Don't interfere with their hiring process.

> My worry is that I will end up costing the charity money by allowing them to buy me flights and accommodation only for me to not use them or by delaying until the flights double in price.

Do you know for a fact they are buying non-refundable travel plans?

People miss flights, flights get delayed and transfers are missed, and people don't always buy travel insurance. There are many other ways you can loose lots of money on travel.

What happens if before the flight you catch the flu, or pull your back or you get fired?

The person planning this travel is the person responsible for managing the risks.

So I would continue with the hiring process as normal. If you have to give your current employer X number of days notice, then this is how many days you until you are available.